# OneDrive REST API - Upload - Content of .png file converted to jpeg

Tags: rest, onedrive

When using the OneDrive REST API to upload files, the content of some files with a .png extension is automatically converted to JPEG. I'm able to reproduce the problem with both documented upload methods.
Sample png files:
http://www39.zippyshare.com/v/59255310/file.html
http://www2.zippyshare.com/v/11270772/file.html

For reference the shortened requests:

**PUT method**

```
PUT https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.<removed>/files/i2.png HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
<removed - no Content-Type header>
Content-Length: 33579
Host: apis.live.net
```

When the Content-Type in the header of the PUT request is set to application/octet-stream the following error is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Live-API/19.7.925.4009 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
<removed>

{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_body_invalid_media_type", 
      "message": "The Content-Type header 'application/octet-stream' isn't supported."
   }
}
```

**POST method**

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.<removed>/files HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=735b1931-a2bb-4970-8142-373848528fcb
<removed>
Content-Length: 33767
Host: apis.live.net

--735b1931-a2bb-4970-8142-373848528fcb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="i2.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

.PNG<removed>
--735b1931-a2bb-4970-8142-373848528fcb--
```

**Other OneDrive APIs**

The problem does not happen with the API (skyapi.onedrive.live.com/API/2) Microsoft is using on the OneDrive website and in the Windows desktop client (skydrive.exe).

**OneDrive developers:**

Instead of returning a 415 error in the PUT request, would it be possible to support requests where the Content-Type: application/octet-stream header is set? In this case the data should be left as is without doing any data conversion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented behaviour as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx (see the first note under uploading).

If you want to disable conversion, you can set `downsize_photo_uploads=false` in your query string.

Comment: Thank you. I must have overlooked this query param. Unfortunately there is a new problem now: The file size OneDrive reports is incorrect. The 21 KB PNG shows as a 38.4 KB PNG on the OneDrive website and this corresponds with the size param of the REST photo object.

Comment: For reference, the new question/report has been created here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906007/onedrive-wrong-size-for-png-files